# Move a fix from a branch to the default branch

Tags: mercurial, merge, dvcs

I have a mercurial repository with two branches (default and branch1) I have a fix that I wanted to do on default but I made it in branch1. I don't want to merge from branch1 to default. Is there a way to move that fix to the default branch without moving anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you commit a changeset on the wrong branch, then you have two options:

1. **copy** the changeset to the right branch with [transplant](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TransplantExtension). The change will now appear twice in your history, but standard three-way merge will deal with that just fine. I've described that scenario in my [**guide to named branches**](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/tasks/#transplanting-changes).
2. **move** the changeset to the right branch with something like [mq](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension). This should only be done for changesets that haven't been pushed anywhere since you're [editing history](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EditingHistory).

Comment: Nice. I'll try this way, also.

Comment: I would recommend to always merge the branches right after you do a transplant if possible. This will avoid nasty merge conflicts later on if someone makes a change to the transplanted code.

E.g. in your case it sounds like it should be fine to merge default into branch1, which will take care of the possible conflict this may cause later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transplant, https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts but it requires the transplant extension.